# What standard says about anonymous namespace and internal linkage?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

I'm curious about this fact as I came up with the following code:

```
namespace
{
    int my_variable = 12;
    void get_data_a_lot() {}
}


int main()
{
    my_variable++;

    get_data_a_lot();
}
```

and compiling with msvc I get the following:

```
00E 00000000 SECT4  notype       External     | ?my_variable@?A0x087c0a53@@3HA (int `anonymous namespace'::my_variable)
025 00000000 SECT6  notype ()    Static       | ?get_data_a_lot@?A0x087c0a53@@YAXXZ (void __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::get_data_a_lot(void))
```

But when I compile with gcc I get the following:

```
002 00000000 SECT2  notype       Static       | _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_111my_variableE
003 00000000 SECT1  notype ()    Static       | _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_114get_data_a_lotEv
```

So the question is: Is it correct behavior that "my_variable" is External or is it compiler bug?

Comment: But does MSVC *let* you access it from another translation unit? The name mangling could be what makes it impossible.

Comment: I understand that it cannot be accessed from another TU but as I think linker would get it as input and would try to process it. So linking would become slower. Maybe I'm wrong. Correct me pls, if it works other way.

Comment: Which version of MSVC are you using? Which version of GCC? What flags and options are you passing to the compilers? And which C++ standard are the compilers complying with? Because the linkage rules of [unnamed namespaces](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces) changed with the C++11 standard.

Comment: @Andrei - I seriously doubt it has a noticeable effect on linking speed, certainly not enough to even warrant calling it a QoI bug. Surprising, maybe. I'm willing to grant you that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. C++14, O0 both. MSVC 2017, mingw gcc 8.3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard says

> **[basic.link]**
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.link#4) An unnamed namespace or a namespace declared directly or
>   indirectly within an unnamed namespace has internal linkage. All other
>   namespaces have external linkage. A name having namespace scope that
>   has not been given internal linkage above has the same linkage as the
>   enclosing namespace if it is the name of
>
> - a variable; or
> - [...]

According to which `my_variable` *should* have internal linkage. One must bear in mind however that *how* linkage is implemented is entirely up to the implementation. The fact MSVC doesn't tag the symbol `Static` doesn't mean it's in violation of the standard. All the standard requires is an entity whose name has internal linkage is distinct from entities with the same name in other TU's, such that it can only be referred to by that name in the single TU it's defined in. The name mangling could very well be how MSVC easily accomplishes it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and reference! The only thing, I want to point, that adding the word "static" before "my_variable" makes linkage "Static".

02B 00000000 SECTB  notype       Static       | ?my_variable@?A0x087c0a53@@3HA (int `anonymous namespace'::my_variable)

Comment: @Andrei - See, now that seems wrong for consistency reasons. That may be a bug.